# PHP, simple class for working with MySql and mysql_close problem

Tags: php, mysql, class

Here is a simple php class for working with database. The problem with this class is in `__destruct` method, that launch `mysql_close` function.
If I create two DB objects that are situated in code very close it cause an error. It looks like that mysql_close close all database connections, not just his own($this->dbLink). Why it is happens?

```
    require_once("modules/required/OptionsReader/m_OptionsReader.php");

    class DB{
        private $dbLink;

        public function  __construct() {
            $options = new OptionsReader();
            $DBSettings = $options->getDBSettings();
            $this->dbLink = mysql_connect($DBSettings->getAddress(),$DBSettings->getUserName(),$DBSettings->getPswd());
            @mysql_select_db($DBSettings->getDBName()) or die( "Unable to select database");
            mysql_query( "set names 'utf8'" );
        }

        public function  __destruct() {
            mysql_close($this->dbLink);
        }


        public function launchQuery($query){
            return mysql_query($query);
        }
    }
?>
```

P.S. I know that the simple solution of this problem is just to make from __desctuctor  close() function and launch it manually, but it will be great to understand what is going. Thank you

Comment: Is it possible that `mysql_connect` pools connection objects and won't open 2 connections to the same database if it doesn't have to? At any rate, unless your script will run for a very long period, you can let PHP close the connections itself. I think it's going to be much simpler that way.

Comment: So does php close mysql connection automatically and so nothing to worry about at all?

Comment: mysql does close the connection when your script is done, and it generally not something you need to worry about, but it might be more appropriate to have your class check for an active connection before opening another.

Comment: You could use `mysqli` instead, which will probably work more closely to what you expect.  http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@zneak is correct. `mysql_connect` does pool connections.  The question is, why do you want to close the connection?  In all my years of developing in PHP, I can count on one hand the number of times that I have used `mysql_connect`, I almost exclusively use `mysql_pconnect`

From http://php.net/mysql_pconnect —

> Establishes a persistent connection to
>   a MySQL server.
>
> mysql_pconnect() acts very much like
>   mysql_connect() with two major
>   differences.
>
> First, when connecting, the function
>   would first try to find a (persistent)
>   link that's already open with the same
>   host, username and password. If one is
>   found, an identifier for it will be
>   returned instead of opening a new
>   connection.
>
> Second, the connection to the SQL
>   server will not be closed when the
>   execution of the script ends. Instead,
>   the link will remain open for future
>   use (mysql_close() will not close
>   links established by
>   mysql_pconnect()).